# IntelliJ IDEA, hotkey to remove unused namespaces in MXML

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, mxml, hotkeys

I often use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> combination to remove unused imports. Does something like this exist for unused namespaces? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not yet.

It has already been [reported on their issue tracking system](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-61697), so let's hope they can fix it soon.